# Events in Chained Fallback Function Cause VirtualMachineError

Tags: solidity, events, delegatecall, calldata, fallback-function

I’m working on an upgradeable contract that uses `fallback` functions with `inline assembly` `delegatecall` and `call` calls (using `calldatacopy` and `returndatacopy`) to route internal and external function calls . Function calls often get routed through three fallback functions before executed. I have a decent set of tests and everything passes successfully. However if I emit an event in the initial fallback function, contract execution stops with a `brownie.exceptions.VirtualMachineError: revert` on chained `fallback` calls. Once the emit is removed the test suite passes again without issue.

Any ideas what's going wrong here or how I can troubleshoot this? I have layered calldata, do events impact that in some way? This brings back memories of uninitialized pointers…

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it with other clients like geth, ganache, besu, etc. Perhaps it is something wrong with brownie implementation. If it happens with many clients then likely is a problem with the code, one option is to debug step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract makes intra-contract calls through the fallback function. The issue was with calls to view functions, which compile into `staticcalls` that can’t emit events.